# How do I get the copy constructor called over a variadic constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

In the following code, the variadic constructor is called twice.  How can I get the copy constructor to be called instead of the single argument version of the variadic constructor when appropriate?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(const Foo &)
    {
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    Foo(Args&&... args)
    {
        std::cout << "variadic constructor\n";
    }

    std::string message;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f1;
    Foo f2(f1); // this calls the variadic constructor, but I want the copy constructor.
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the fact that the constructor is variadic.  The following class with a non-variadic constructor template exhibits the same behavior:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() { }

    Foo(const Foo& x)
    {
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }

    template <typename T>
    Foo(T&& x)
    {
        std::cout << "template constructor\n";
    }

};
```

The problem is that the constructor template is a better match.  To call the copy constructor, a qualification conversion is required to bind the non-const lvalue `f1` to `const Foo&` (the const qualification must be added).

To call the constructor template, no conversions are required:  `T` can be deduced to `Foo&`, which after reference collapsing (`Foo& &&` -> `Foo&`), gives the parameter `x` type `Foo&`.

You can work around this by providing a second copy constructor that has a non-const lvalue reference parameter `Foo&`.

Comment: There’s slightly more to it, namely reference collapsing (how was that called?), i.e. `T&&&` => `T&` because otherwise an lvalue  (`f1`) couldn’t bind to `T&&`.

Answer (score 6):

Just provide an exact-match overload, i.e. one with a non-`const` `Foo&`, in addition to the conventional copy constructor. Then you can delegate the call via an explicit cast:

```
Foo(Foo& other) : Foo{const_cast<Foo const&>(other)} { }
```

Comment: Shouldn't const_cast be used?

Comment: @Fan No, why? Non const to const is an implicit conversion by the C++ rules, we just use an explicit cast (= `static_cast`) to force it here. `const_cast` is only needed to cast *away* constness.

Comment: According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast, const_cast "converts between types with different cv-qualification." It is not necessarily from const to non-const.

Comment: @Fan I didn’t dispute that. I simply said that you don’t *need* it here, `static_cast` works too. But you’re right, there’s an argument to be made for using `const_cast` here, because this prevents accidentally changing the type (which `static_cast` might do if you have a typo in the type). You could probably even use `std::forward<Foo const&>` here but that’s abusing its semantics slightly.