# template copy constructor

Tags: c++

Given the following code, does Foo have copy constructor? Is it safe to use Foo with STL containers?

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo() {}

   template <typename T>
   Foo(const T&) {}   
};
```

Answer (score 10):

The standard explicitly says that a copy constructor is a non-templated constructor that takes a reference to a possibly const-volatile object of the same type. In the code above you have a *conversion* but not *copy* constructor (i.e. it will be used for everything *but* copies, where the implicitly declared constructor will be used).

> Does `Foo` have a copy constructor?

Yes, the implicitly declared/defined copy constructor.

> Is it safe to use `Foo` with standard library containers?

With the current definition of `Foo` it is, but in the general case, it depends on what members `Foo` has and whether the implicitly defined copy constructor manages those correctly.

Comment: What happens if this is declared before the template `Foo(const Foo&) = delete;`? Does the class now have no copy constructor or does the template get called instead?

Comment: If the copy constructor is deleted, then the class doesn't have one. ;-)

Comment: @nightcracker then there is no copy constructor and the compiler gives an error (unless you have an expression where e.g. the move copy constructor could have been used). The key is that the copy constructor is *non-templated*.

Comment: Where *does* the implicit copy constructor get used?  It seems like only for when this type is used as a subobject of a larger type that has a defaulted copy constructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I am not sure I understand the comment. In the code it is not used, but the question talks about being able to use this type in a container (with the concern placed on the copy-constructor). Maybe I should make it clearer that the implicitly-declared copy constructor is only defined if *used*? Is that your concern? The copy constructor will be defined whenever an object of this type is copied, it need not be a part of a larger object (say: `Foo f, g(f);`

Answer (score 4):

According to the Standard, a copy-constructor must be one of the following signature:

```
Foo(Foo &);
Foo(Foo const &);
Foo(Foo volatile &);
Foo(Foo const volatile &);

Foo(Foo&, int = 0, );
Foo(Foo&, int = 0, float = 1.0); //i.e the rest (after first) of the 
                                 //parameter(s) must have default values!
```

Since the template constructor in your code doesn't match with the form of any of the above, that is **not** *copy*-constructor.

Comment: And can have default parameters also

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: Yes, that too.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo` has a compiler generated copy constructor, which cannot be replaced by the template conversion constructor you have provided.

```
Foo f0;
Foo f1(f0); // calls compiler-synthesized copy constructor
Foo f2(42); // calls template conversion constructor with T=int
```

Comment: This seems NOT to actually call the copy constructor.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037644/how-do-i-get-the-copy-constructor-called-over-a-variadic-constructor