# Trying to implement a sort of initializer list syntax for Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, eigen, c++17

I like Eigen's comma-initialization syntax, but I would prefer it to resemble initializer-list initialization.

I've tried to implement something like this by myself, but I've run into problems that I'm not able to solve.

My approach is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

template <int Rows= Eigen::Dynamic, int Cols= Rows>
class MyMatrix: public Eigen::Matrix<double,Rows,Cols>
{
private:
  using Matrix= Eigen::Matrix<double,Rows,Cols>;

public:
  MyMatrix(): Matrix() {
    std::cout << "MyMatrix()\n";
    if /* constexpr */ (Rows!=Eigen::Dynamic) Matrix::setZero(); }

  template <typename Derived>
  MyMatrix(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &Other): Matrix(Other) // (2)
    { std::cout << "MyMatrix(const MatrixBase<Derived> &Other)\n"; }

  template <typename TFirst,typename... TRest/*,typename= enable_if_t<NoIdea::value>*/>
  MyMatrix(TFirst &&First,TRest &&... Rest) { *this << First, (Rest, ...); }
};

int main()
{
MyMatrix<3> Mat1= MyMatrix<3>::Identity();
MyMatrix<3> Mat2= { MyMatrix<3>::Identity() };
MyMatrix<3> Mat3= { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, // Runtime error
                    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
MyMatrix<3> Mat4= MyMatrix<3>::Identity()+MyMatrix<3>::Ones();
MyMatrix<3> Mat5= {};
}
```

This code compiles with g++-6 but it has (at least) two problems:

1. Constructor (2) is never called and I don't know how to encourage the compiler to select it for appropriate objects.
2. I get an assertion failed for the `MyMatrix` instance that actualy uses an initialitacion list (`Too few coefficients passed to comma initializer (operator<<)`). It seems that the fold expression does not work as I'd like.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to do some research into the ['rule of 3'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))  as while you're not dealing with pointers, you are trying to use the assignment operator...

Comment: @UKMonkey I haven't defined any of this '3'. Would the default generated ones cause a wrong behaviour?

Comment: Mis-read your constructor (2) sorry.
In any case, the reason why it's not getting called is because it uses either the assignment operator or the move operator.  None of your variables are created with the (), but with a "=".

Comment: Your variadic constructor [is prefered to the (2) constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11037644/1364752) because of `const`/reference matching. If I'm not mistaken, you should probably add `typename = std::enable_it_t<not std::is_same<std::decay_t<TFirst>, Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>>::value>` to make sure that overload resolution happens the way you want for your constructors. You might have the same problem with your copy constructor, etc...

Comment: @Morwenn This was the first I thought. The problem is that then `MyMatrix<6> m= { MyMatrix<3>::Zero(), MyMatrix<3>::Zero(), MyMatrix<3>::Zero(), MyMatrix<3>::Zero() };` won't work. It there a way to prevent the empty pack expansion to happen successfully? This would solve the problem.

Comment: Note that there is a pending feature request for initializer-list support: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=954 (big parts of the discussion is only partially related to initializer lists). I have not looked into your (remaining) initializer list so far.

Comment: @chtz I knew of that discussion. However, Eigen developers seemed somewhat reluctant to the idea. Furthermore, they appear to deal with homogeneous initialization (`std::initializer_list<Scalar>`). I would like to have full comma-initialization functionality (heterogeneous init-lists).

Answer (score 2):

I have just realized about the error in the fold expression. It should read:

```
(*this << First),...,Rest;
```

**EDIT:** Since I am not interested in init-lists with a single element, the following solution avoids the constructor ambiguity problem:

```
template <typename TFirst,typename TSecond,typename... TRest>
MyMatrix(TFirst &&First,TSecond &&Second,TRest &&... Rest)
  { ((*this << First, Second), ... , Rest); }
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile with g++-6 (probably because of [bug 68377](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68377)), but it does with clang++-3.8.

Now I can write:

```
MyMatrix<3> m= { MyMatrix<2,2>::Ones(), MyMatrix<2,1>::Zero(),
                 MyMatrix<1,2>::Zero(), 0.0 };
```

instead of:

```
MyMatrix<3> m= ( MyMatrix<3>() << MyMatrix<2,2>::Ones(), MyMatrix<2,1>::Zero(),
                                  MyMatrix<1,2>::Zero(), 0.0 ).finished();
```

Comment: @AviGinsburg Yes. It does. The underlying problem is that my variadic constructor "eats" all the value initializations taking arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I came up:

```
// very dark magic
template<int M, int N=M> 
constexpr auto MakeMatrix = [](auto m, auto... ms) {
return ((Matrix<M,N>()<<m),...,ms).finished();
};
```

where `Matrix<M,N>` is:

```
template<int M, int N=M>
using Matrix = Eigen::Matrix<double, M, N>;
```

and the usage is like so:

```
auto v = Matrix<2,1>::Zero();
auto m = Matrix<2>::Identity();
std::cout<< MakeMatrix<2,3>(v,m);
```

(output)

```
0 1 0
0 0 1
```